# 'Multiplying' by 0 in a field, field axiom proofs

Tags: field-theory, axioms, proof-explanation

The question says:
[image]

The solution set was posted and there are a few things I don't quite understand from it.

[image: http://i.imgur.com/8HkzCHj.png]

For the first one, I'm not entirely sure what's happening. It appears to be using the case where a<sup>2</sup> = 0, but I'm not sure where the (a · a) comes from. If that's supposed to represent a<sup>2</sup>, I don't recall a field axiom that would make that work as well as have it end up being 'a' in the end.

The second one seems to use the multiplicative inverse but I'm unsure as to what a<sup>2</sup> · a<sup>-1</sup> would return. The multiplicative inverse would seem to work only for a · a<sup>-1</sup>, not for a<sup>2</sup> unless I'm misunderstanding the field axiom.

The last one seems the result already proven but also uses the multiplicative inverse axiom in a way I don't quite understand with a<sup>2</sup> · a<sup>-1</sup> = 1, apparently.

Any enlightenment on this question would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$a^2$ is an informal abbreviation for $a\cdot a$.

As to your later question about $a^2\cdot a^{-1}$, it means $(a\cdot a)\cdot a^{-1}$. By associativity this is $a\cdot (a\cdot a^{-1})$, which is $a\cdot 1$, which is $a$.

Comment: Id say it's also a pretty formal abbreviation for $a \cdot a$

Comment: Ah thanks, wasn't sure how a^2 was defined in a field as I don't recall there being a specific axiom for it.

Comment: You are welcome. Probably $x^2$ may not have been defined explicitly, since it is a familiar abbreviation for $x\cdot x$ in elementary algebra. If we are being formal, we define $x^n$ by induction: $x^1=x$, and for $n\ge 1$, $x^{n+1}=(x^n)\cdot x$. Then one extends the definition to $0$ and negative integers, by $x^0=1$ and $x^{-n}=(x^{-1})^n$.

Answer (score 2):

There appears to be a typo in the last bit. Here's what I would write:

> If $a^2=1$, then - since we know that $ab=1$ - we have $a^2=ab$. So multiplying both sides by $a^{-1}$ we get $a=b$, a contradiction.

I don't see how the author deduces $b=1$ here; I think "$1$" should be "$a$".

Comment: Yeah was confused here as well, thanks!